# Data extract from one sheet to another sheet with multiple criteria in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have large data with 6 columns in sheet 2. I would like to extract the data from sheet 2 to sheet 5 based on multiple criteria.
my sheet 2 data ...

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1xEt.jpg)

so, i write following code to extract data from sheet 2 to sheet5.

```
Sheet2.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheet5.Range("a3:d3"), _
CopytoRange:=Sheet5.Range("a10:k10"), Unique:=False
'Columns(6).AutoFit
```

problem is when I run above code it displays all data from sheet 2, but it is not met with my criteria.

for example  if user selects following details... 
Place   : USA

Month   : Jul-19

Variety : I

remarks : PR

output should be like these...
[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfNED.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The `CriteriaRange` is expecting headers AND criteria, furthermore the `CopyToRange` will work assigning it just a single cell (you wouldn't know pre-filtering the amount of rows it should contain with each filtering). So with the following setup on sheet1 and sheet5:

***Sheet1:***

[image]

***Sheet5:***

[image]

***Running the following code:***

```
Sub AdvancedFiltr()

Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=Sheet5.Range("A1:F2"), CopyToRange:=Sheet5.Range("A4")

End Sub
```

***Results in Sheet5:***

[image]

---

Some remarks:

- `CriteriaRange`: The headers need to match the headers from the database exactly.
- `CriteriaRange`: You don’t need to have every header, just the ones you want to filter by.
- `CopyToRange`: It's wise to clear the range on Sheet5 before you apply another filter.
- I really think [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-copy/) is a great article on `AdvancedFilter` to make clear how it works.